# Освоение сетей. Клиент сервер

Tags: c++, сеть

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int Sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in SockAddr;
    char *mas = new char[100];
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(9734);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "176.100.250.28", &(SockAddr.sin_addr));
    cout << SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr << endl;
    bind(Sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr));
    listen(Sock_fd, 1);
    while(1)
    {
        int SockListen_fd = accept(Sock_fd, NULL, NULL);
        while(1)
        {
            char buf[2000];
            int b = recv(SockListen_fd, buf, 2000, 0);
            if (b <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            cout << buf << endl;
        }
        close(SockListen_fd);
    }
    close(Sock_fd);
    return 0;
}


    #include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int Sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in SockAddr;
    char *mas = new char[100];
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "176.100.250.28", &(SockAddr.sin_addr));
    cout << SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr << endl;
    bind(Sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr));
    connect(Sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr));
    send(Sock_fd, "data", 5, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Сервер и клиент. Отправляю данные, ничего не происходит, дебажу send выдает SIGPIPE? В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: У вас вечный цикл записи ответа клиенту

Comment: @monobogdan, не помогло, и он не циклится. Дело именно в клиенте, потому что я его дебажил и send выдал SIGPIPE